# Symfony 5 no muestra la barra de debug con proyectos website-skeleton

Tags: depuración, symfony5

Actualmete estoy aprendiendo Symfony, y me he encontrado con la primera difcultad.
Tras realizar la instalacion de symfony/website-skeleton, no veo la barra de debug, en cambio, si instalo la version basica (symfony/skeleton), aparece tras ejecutar estos comandos:

```
symfony composer req profiler --dev
symfony composer req logger
symfony composer req debug --dev
```

Estoy usando Symfony CLI, pero usando composer directamente, ocurre exactamente lo mismo.

Despues de instalar symfony/website-skeleton, tambien he instalado los paquetes indicados arriba, pero no parece hacer ningun cambio. En los cambios de git, no se refleja ninguna modificacion de los archivos.

¿Alguna idea sobre como solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**RESPUESTA RAPIDA**

Verificar el archivo **.env** que la variable **APP_ENV** este igualada a dev, ejemplo APP_ENV=dev

**EXPLICACIÓN**

Symfony trabaja en dos modos "Que yo cosca", el modo **Desarrollo** y el modo **Producción**, si la variable del archivo **.env** esta igualada a **prod**, eso quiere decir que estas en modo producción y tu aplicación web se vera como si ya estuviera desplegada en un servidor, en cambio el modo **dev** te saldra la barra de debug.

Si no te funciona al cambiar la variable a **dev**, intenta con ejecutar este comando por consola.

```
symfony server:prod --off
```

Comment: Verificado, en .env la variable APP_ENV=DEV, es correcto.
El comando que indicas, arroja este error:   remove D:\Server\www\Symfony5full\.prod: The system cannot find the file specified.
No he tenido que realizar ningun cambio, la configuracion aparece como indicas, hay que tener en cuenta, que no es una aplicacion todavia, sino el website-skeleton descargado tal cual.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví esta situación realizando lo siguiente:

`symfony composer require symfony/apache-pack`

y cuando hace la pregunta de:
`Do you want to execute this recipe?`
Responder "Yes"

Un saludo.